# Object Oriented Programming: object initialization of a class by passing the instance of other class

Tags: python, class, object

I have created a test subject to understand my Object Oriented Programming.

```
class Asset(object):
    def __init__(self, project):
        self.project = project

    def do_something(self):
        return self.project.x, self.project.y, True


class Project(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.asset = Asset(self) # Is this correct?

    def call_do_something(self):
        return self.asset.do_something()


project_test = Project('foo', 'bar')
project_test.call_do_something()
```

Can I initialize class `Asset` as an attribute of class `Project` by passing the instance of class `Project` like I have done in `self.asset = Asset(self)`? If yes, what is the term for it? If not, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Looks fine. Have you tried running it or encountered any problem?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you perfectly can. This design pattern is called **Composition over inheritance**

> **Composition over inheritance** (or composite reuse principle) in
>   object-oriented programming is the principle that classes should
>   achieve polymorphic behavior and code reuse by their composition (by
>   containing instances of other classes that implement the desired
>   functionality) rather than inheritance from a base or parent class

Read [more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct.

You can also pass an `Asset` as a parameter of `Project` constructor, like this:

```
class Asset(object):
    def __init__(self, project=None):
        self.project = project

class Project(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, asset):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.asset = asset
        self.asset.project = self
```

That way, you can initialise a project as follow:

```
project = Project('foo', 'bar', Asset())
```

The relationship is done automatically by the `Project` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

This may be called [object composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition), and you are mainly expressing: a Project "has a" Assert. In most languages, "field", "property" etc. are used to denote the reference object (Assert here).

For design pattern Composition over inheritance, it may be more complicated: The component and the composite will have the same interface (derived from it), and normally composite will have a list of the components.